# What is the best way to solve a file that has 1m rows of data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very big file with the following format:

```
Sitename
BW: ?M

Time           Duration Bits /sec   Bits In /sec    Bits Out /sec
3/3/2015 23:55  300 799.3333333 358.6666667 440.6666667
3/1/2015 0:00   301 725.820598  339.1627907 386.6578073
.
.
2000 more lines

Sitename
BW: ?M

Time    Duration    Bits /sec   Bits In /sec    Bits Out /sec
3/7/2015 23:55  300 799.3333333 358.6666667 440.6666667
3/8/2015 0:00   301 725.820598  339.1627907 386.6578073
..
..
```

The file mostly contains data like that, each site has like 2000 rows. I want to get **"time, highest bits in, highest bits out"** for every site. I have a vba script to get the highest bits in/out, but still very time-consuming to go through every single site. I actually timed myself and noticed that it took me about 2 hours to record 100 sites. Is there any other way to process this faster?

My current script is:

```
Sub Largest()
'Cells with dates also return a value, and get covered for determining largest value. Percentages will convert and return numerics.

Dim rng As Range
Dim maximum As Double



'Set range from which to determine largest value
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("E10052:E12055")



'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range

maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

'Displays largest value
MsgBox maximum




End Sub
```

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion-based. I would recommend to close it. Thanks for the understanding. Best regards,

Comment: If your current script is slow and you want help to make it faster, the best approach is to *include your current script*.  Otherwise there's no way to help you without guessing what you're doing right now.

Comment: I have just updated my post with my current script. Basically, when the messagebox shows the max, I copy it and paste to a new spreadsheet and then Ctrl+F with the max value to find the time...then copy the time and paste it the same place...

Comment: What type of file is it?  Can you share an example (maybe smaller) file via something like dropbox?

Answer (score 2):

Using a database rather than a spreadsheet will be able to generate your answer in seconds rather than hours.

Comment: You mean Microsoft Access?

Comment: If that is all you have access to then it would help, but I would recommend a full DBMS such as MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I have access to and I can't transfer this file to anywhere else..so I'm stuck with whatever available...

Comment: MySQL (and similar DBMSs) are free to download and install.

Comment: Say I'll install it tomorrow, how would I go about finding the solution to my problem?

Comment: I thought your problem was speed? This will solve that problem for you.

Comment: so let's assume that it will. What commands would you use to make it happen?

Comment: How do you plan to set up your database table?